# AWS Cloudwatch Alarm Issue

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, dead-letter, cloudwatch-alarms

```
Alarm
XXXX-dev-callbackFunctionErrorsAlarm-ADEBCL4KV1

Description
Lambda Function Errored

Previous State
INSUFFICIENT_DATA

Error Received : Threshold Crossed: 1 out of the last 1 datapoints [1.0 (17/08/21 03:54:00)] was greater than or equal to the threshold (1.0) (minimum 1 datapoint for OK -> ALARM transition).
```

[image]
configuration

I have a standard SQS and Dead Letter SQS, which when has a load starts to raise the above alarm. Flow is working fine unless Huge load is there
But in both cases, Alarm is getting raised.

Can someone please help with this?

Comment: can you please share your alarm config?

Comment: Configuration screenshot attached

Comment: Sorry, what is the issue? You don't want the alarm to trigger?

Comment: I want to understand how this is getting triggred
Whats the meaning of 

Threshold Crossed: 1 out of the last 1 datapoints [1.0 (17/08/21 03:54:00)] was greater than or equal to the threshold (1.0) (minimum 1 datapoint for OK -> ALARM transition).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Threshold modification helped resolve the issue depending on Load Test results